# RDD Json file processing

Tags: json, pyspark, google-bigquery, rdd

I imported data from bigquery using the following code on Pyspark:

```
table_data = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
    conf=conf)
```

The output is an RDD framework but has the data in a json format:

```
[(0, u'{"colA":"Value1,Value4"}'), (52, u'{"colA":"Value2"}')]
```

I need to extract all the **Values** in the RDD format. A main concern being the resulting RDD should not contain double quotes for each record.

Required:

```
Value1,Value4
Value2
```

and not:

```
"Value1,Value4"
"Value2"
```

Comment: Can you show your result in a valid python data structure? Do you need another rdd returned as well?

Comment: I need an RDD since I would be using MLlib to implement an algorithm.

Comment: If the json is separated by a "," then its return type will be `str` already. How would you know the type of each `Value`, such as float, int, str and so on?

Comment: Do you need a RDD of `sc.parallelize(["Value1,Value4", "Value2"])` for instance?

Comment: @WillianFuks Every value is a string.

Comment: @Psidom Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your question this is what you are looking for:

```
import json
data = sc.parallelize([(0, u'{"colA":"Value1,Value4"}'), (52, u'{"colA":"Value2"}')])
data = data.map(lambda x: (json.loads(x[1])['colA']))
print(data.collect())
```

Results:

```
['Value1,Value4', 'Value2']
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this as a list of lists?
[['Value1,Value4'],[Value2']]

Comment: you could add `split` in the json return, something like `json.loads(x[1])['colA'].split(',')`. Or if you don't want to separate the values then converting to list should already work: `[json.loads(x[1])['colA']]`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly load it with `json` module:

```
import json

table_data.map(lambda t: json.loads(t[1]).get("colA")).collect()
# [u'Value1,Value4', u'Value2']
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know in sometime if this worked since I am currently running out of memory. Thanks for your time.